# Как через jQuery изменить несколько значений одного CSS свойства

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css-selectors

Есть необходимость при помощи скрипта заставить объект **одновременно** увеличиваться и вращаться. 
Как в CSS это написать я понимаю 
`.wood {transform: scale(value), rotateZ(value)}`
Но через jQuery как только не пробовал передавать эти значения, и через массив и через перечисление, всегда срабатывает только одно значение.

Вот примеры из реализации (объявление переменных я думаю нет смысла тут показывать) 
 
В данном примере срабатывает только последнее свойство `rotateZ`
`$('.wood').css({'transform': 'scale('+zoom+')', 'transform': 'rotateZ('+angle+'deg)'});`

В этих двух вариантах только первое значение срабатывает, консоль ошибок никаких не выдает
`$('.wood').css('transform', 'scale('+zoom+')', 'rotateZ('+zoom+'deg)');`
`$('.wood').css('transform', 'scale('+zoom+')' +','+ 'rotateZ('+zoom+'deg)');`

Подскажите, как правильно это прописать, чтобы изменить сразу два свойства одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* Мультифункциональные значения */

transform: perspective(500px) translate(10px, 0, 20px) rotateY(3deg);

Запятая лишняя:

$('.wood').css('transform', 'scale('+2+') rotateZ('+15+'deg)');

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало.
Получается я в CSS был не прав думая, что верно через запятую